# Custom Slot for Full Name of User and Linking multiple account in Single alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-account-linking

I have two queries related to Alexa Skill -

1. I am using the Account Linking feature, But when I logged in with one account I am unable to login with another account, any idea? for more information on this please refer here

- https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/233563/how-to-delinking-an-linked-account-from-my-alexa-s.html

2. For User Full Name I have created a custom `Slot`, but unable to fetch Exact Full Name spoken to Echo show device by the user, for example, Use speaks `Danny Stone` but Alexa device capture it as "Danny", Dannys tone", "Danni" etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For the name, do a two or three slot response pattern on that intent. First name can use Amazon's built in first name slot type. For the other(s), you'll need custom slots with lots of examples.

For unlinking an account, check out this option: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/skill-activation-api.html#disable-and-unlink

Comment: I don't think this is good way to go with for name using multiple slots, for account delinking ill look into it in the link you shared. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. I read your query on the other forum. I would suggest you clear the cache of your Alexa app if you are logging on to your phone. If it does not help then open an incognito browser and disable enable the skill and link the desired account.
2. Use custom AMAZON.FirstName intent or AMAZON.Person intent for the names. I am not sure that it will be able to recognize some tricky names.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 1. Cleared alexa/Chrome app cache but doesn't work, Also I don't want to go with Incognito mode as Users will not aware of this so it is bit difficult for them 2. I used ` AMAZON.Person` but its not capturing name with FirstName and LastName but recognise well single word name.